# Django bulk_create check for duplicate entry of multiple fields

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm trying to use [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) for large dataset insert since i can't use get_or_create() because of N^N problem

Here is the table i'm trying to create my entries on:

```
class SeatType(models.Model):
    ... other fields


class UserSeat(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("backend.User", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_seat', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seat_type = models.ForeignKey("backend.SeatType", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_seat_type', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And here is my implementation:

```
users = User.objects.all()
user_seats = [
      UserSeat(
              user=user,
              seat_type=SeatType.objects.all()[random_entry]
      )
      for user in users
]
UserSeat.objects.bulk_create(user_seats, None, ignore_conflicts=True)
```

The thing is i want to check for duplicate entry unique with 2 columns(user, seat_type) values

For example:

```
user       |seat_type  | ...
---------- | --------- | ...
1          |1          | ...
2          |2          | ...
3          |4          | ...
4          |1          | ...
1          |1          | ...
3          |4          | ...
```

(1, 1) and (3, 4) is invalid when inserting
But `ignore_conflict` only trigger on 1 unique column(which is not what i want which is unique value of 2 columns), i'm looking for something like `defaults` of [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), My DataBase is MySQL.

Columns can be duplicate but each row must be unique pair of `user` and `seat_type` data

Comment: Show us your AnotherTable model

Comment: @iklinac i had updated with the tables and my implementation

Comment: I don't see any constraints on UserSeat table, is this full model

Comment: @iklinac yes i don't have any constrains for it because columns can be duplicate, i would like to check for unique row with bulk_create(), should i add that? and how do i add it?

Comment: You need unique key constraint to check for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add Unique [constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/) as `ignore_conflicts` is resolved on database level as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

```
class UserSeat(models.Model):

    ...

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'seat_type'], 
            name='unique_user_seat')
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to use ManyToManyField in SeatType model and set though to UserSeat model, no need to create manual any more.

e.g.

```
class SeatType(models.Model):
    ... other fields
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserSeat')

class UserSeat(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("backend.User", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_seat', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seat_type = models.ForeignKey("backend.SeatType", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_seat_type', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...other fields (modified, created, ...)
```

For more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships